# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 when calling azure rest api through JUnit

Tags: java, rest, azure, junit

This is the error which i get -

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
```

Here is my method to call Azure service management rest api -

```
private static InputStream processGetRequest(URL url, String keyStore,
            String keyStorePassword) throws UnrecoverableKeyException,
            KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = getSSLSocketFactory(keyStore,
                keyStorePassword);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory);
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.addRequestProperty("x-ms-version", "2013-10-01");
        InputStream responseStream = con.getInputStream();
        return responseStream;
    }
```

URL looks like this -

```
String url = String
            .format("https://management.core.windows.net/%s/services/hostedservices",
                            subscriptionId);
```

This method works fine when i run as a java application. However, when i make a call to this method in the Junits, the first Test which calls this method fails and i get the above http 403 error.

I can't find any reason as to why it fails only for the first time. Is there any other parameter which i need to set to successfully make these rest calls to azure service management api?

Comment: this only comes when you have not setup your certs properly.

Comment: I have used the following command to create the keystore         'keytool -genkeypair -alias mydomain -keyalg RSA -keystore WindowsAzureKeyStore.jks -keysize 2048 -storepass "test123";'              And this command to export to cer file                              '- keytool -v -export -file D:\WindowsAzureSMAPI.cer -keystore WindowsAzureKeyStore.jks                                               -alias mydomain'                                                   Am I missing anything?

Comment: Have you uploaded this generated cert on azure ?

Comment: Yes, I have. I am able to make calls to this api through my java application. It is through the Junit when it fails only for the first time. All other subsequent requests give proper response